# Installing Wamp and Composer on Windows 10

Tags: php, wamp, windows-10

I just installed the Windows 10 Technical Preview, and now I'm trying to install Wamp in order to install Composer on my machine. Yet when I go to use the PHP.exe file from Wamp for Composer, I get the following error:

***The PHP exe file you specified did not execute correctly:  C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe***

I've checked the OpenSSL and it's enabled in all three files for Wamp. I've tried installing the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Wamp, but neither work.

When I try to run PHP from command line, it tells me that ***the php.exe file is missing from my computer***.

Has anyone else run into this problem? If so, have you found a solution for it?

Please and thank you.

Comment: did you try running php yourself from the command line?

Comment: Yep. I get the same error.

Comment: The error is saying that php.exe is missing from my computer.

Comment: Are you running `php.exe` from the folder that contains `php.exe`? i.e. `\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z\`

Comment: Yes, @RiggsFolly I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just installed the Windows 10 Tech Preview myself. I see that it does not come with the Microsoft Visual C/C++ runtimes installed by default.

If you did not install the MSVC 2012, 2010 and 2008 runtimes, then I suggest you do that.

Having those runtimes installed and by entering

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe -v
```

The PHP CLI runs.

If you are still using the 64bit WAMPServer please remember that you need to install the 32bit AND 64bit MSVC runtimes. The wampmanager.exe program is still a 32bit App regardless and therefore needs the 32bit MSVC runtimes. I think it actually only need the MSVC 2008, but it is safer to install all 3 version for both 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Thank you, @RiggsFolly. I installed the runtimes and PHP is running now. I was also able to install Composer. Thanks a million.